# React-native-camera in Ios not working not appearing

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

Making a demo for text Recognition with camera using library `react-native-camera` but camera is not opening

DONE ALL THESE STEPS:

```
npm install react-native-camera --save
react-native link react-native-camera
```

- Go to node_modules ➜ react-native-camera and add RNCamera.xcodeproj
- Expand the RNCamera.xcodeproj ➜ Products folder
- In XCode, in the project navigator, select your project. Add libRNCamera.a to your project's Build Phases ➜ Link Binary With
  Libraries
- Click RNCamera.xcodeproj in the project navigator and go the Build Settings tab. Make sure 'All' is toggled on (instead of
  'Basic').
- In the Search Paths section, look for Header Search Paths and make sure it contains both $(SRCROOT)/../../react-native/React and
  $(SRCROOT)/../../../React - mark both as recursive

  ```
  import { RNCamera } from 'react-native-camera'; 

  camerascan(){
   console.log("camscan=====")
   return(

     <RNCamera
     ref={ref => {
       this.camera = ref;
     }}
     defaultTouchToFocus
     mirrorImage={false} 
     captureAudio={false}
     style={{
       flex: 1,
       justifyContent: 'space-between',
       alignItems: 'center',
       height: Dimensions.get('window').height,
       width: Dimensions.get('window').width,
     }}

     permissionDialogTitle={'Permission to use camera'}
     permissionDialogMessage={'We need your permission to use your camera phone'}


   >
        <View
             style={{
               height: 56,
               backgroundColor: 'transparent',
               alignSelf: 'flex-end',
             }}
           >
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.takePicture.bind(this)}>
       <Text style={styles.capture}> [CAPTURE CARD]</Text>
       </TouchableOpacity>
       </View>
   </RNCamera>  

   );

  }
     takePicture = async function() {
       console.log("takePicture=====")
       if (this.camera) {
        // const options = { quality: 0.5, base64: true };
         // const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync(options)
         const data = await this.camera.takePictureAsync();
         console.warn('takePicture ', data);
         // this.detectText(data.base64)
       }
     };
  ```

No error but camera is not opening.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Done gave the  runtime permissions for camera

import Permissions from 'react-native-permissions'

 componentDidMount()
 {
    this.determinePermission();
  }
  determinePermission(){    
    Permissions.request('camera', { type: 'always' }).then(response => {
      this.setState({ locationPermission: response })

    })

  }
```